# Help Finding Critical Points of a Cubic (with 2 parameters)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

I am trying to find bifurcation points in 1 dimension, but am having trouble finding critical points of

$x'=\mu x -2x^2-x^3+ \delta$

( where $x$ is my variable, $\mu$ is a parameter, and $\delta$  is a small, positive parameter, called a imperfection parameter in the problem)

I know there is a cubic formula to solve something like this, but it's rather messy to deal with on its own, let alone with symbols. I was wondering if there were any better methods of finding the critical points.

Comment: When you write "$x'"$ is this the derivative of the $x$ on the right=hand side or just a different variable?  Then, when you ask about critical points, are you asking where "$x'$" is zero or where $\frac{\mathrm{d}x'}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$?

Comment: It is for a derivative, and yes I'm asking when the equation above is =0

Comment: It's part of a book problem and introduces the concept in the problem. I looked at trying to use the formula to find roots for cubic, but yeah it is rather ugly. I was trying to find out if anyone had anything more straightforward than that.

Comment: Nonlinear ODEs by Grimshaw

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks, I'm going to keep trying as well.

Comment: I realize this from part a), but I don't have much in the way to show that for part b) as an answer.